# Leaflet - markers duplicating, removeLayer, clearLayers only hide markers

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, leaflet, ionic4

`markerGroup: L.LayerGroup;`

```
this.markerGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    this.markerGroup.removeLayer(layer);
});
```

`this.markerGroup.clearLayers();`

removeLayer() and clearLayers() are working as described in the leaflet documentation but I am wondering if there is a way to remove the layer/marker/instance from my markerGroup variable entirely. Even though the markers are cleared/removed, when my refresh button is called it still has the previous markers in the markerGroup variable and adds the same ones again thus duplicating them. This is a problem as I have shadows for these markers which duplicate over each other and eventually becoming 100% opaque. Has anybody got any suggestions or come across this problem before?

Edit: Thanks for the suggestion @Falke Design. map.removeLayer doesn't work for me unfortunately. Hopefully the information below is more helpful:

```
refreshButton() {
    this.markerGroup = new L.LayerGroup;
    clearInterval(this.refreshTimer);
    this.dynamicLatLong = this.map.getCenter();
    this.dynamicZoom = this.map.getZoom();
    this.markerGroup.clearLayers();
    this.polygonGroup.clearLayers();
    this.map.removeLayer(this.markerGroup);
    this.getCurrentAzure();
    this.leafletMap();
}
```

getCurrentAzure() uses a for loop to get the data such as lat, lng, etc. of each instance and assigns it to a variable named marker. Each marker is added to markerGroup with this line:

`marker.addTo(this.markerGroup);`

leafletMap() creates the map and draws the markerGroup onto the map with this line:

```
this.markerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: Can you pls share more code. Have you tried to remove the layer also from the map? `map.removeLayer(layer)`

Comment: Have updated my post @Falker Design. Thanks again for your reply :)

Comment: There is a high chance your issue lies in the details of your getCurrentAzure and/or leafletMap function. Please make sure to share enough code for people to be able to reproduce your issue.